# Смещение часового пояса ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

У меня есть сайт и сервер.
Хочу, чтобы клиентам из разных часовых поясов показывалось разное время.
Всю конвертацию провожу на сервере:

от клиента -

```
return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset);
```

клиенту -

```
return ((DateTimeOffset)dateTime).LocalDateTime;
```

При тесте выяснил, что ASP.NET не умеет сам определять часовой пояс клиента, и его надо определять с помощью JS и передавать при помощи кукис:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset();//gets the timezone offset
```

Вот тут время для вопроса. Каким образом прокидывать смещение от сайта до самого сервера? Я хочу реализовать что-то наподобие

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.***;
```

, без всяких хелперов и обёрток. Но раз в интернете я нигде не нашёл такого способа, значит люди реализовывают смещение времени по другому. 
Как правильно поступить, если я хочу делать конвертацию смещения именно на сервере и желательно стандартными средствами .NET?

UPD: схема такая: пользователь -> ASP.NET MVC 4 -> .exe служба на .NET -> SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартного механизма нет по двум причинам.

Первая из них - местным временем в .NET называют именно системное местное время, а не какое-то еще. А потому TimeZoneInfo.Local возвращает одно и то же для всех потоков и не может быть переопределено.

Вторая - браузер не передает свой часовой пояс через заголовки HTTP (в отличии от языка, который передается в заголовке Accept-Language).

Так что без хелперов и оберток не обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень плохо, если я буду смещение хранить в claims? 
    var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;  
    var offset = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "TimeOffset").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: @vusaldev нет, не плохо, это нормальное место для хранения смещения (но только если ваш сайт недоступен анонимным пользователям)

Comment: @vusaldev но я бы на вашем месте не забывал про метод [`ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh159730(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: спасибо, буду думать

Answer (score 4):

Мы храним объект с разницей во времени между клиентом и сервером в сессии. Вернее, разницу между клиентским временем и UTC. B мастер-странице, при отсутствии этого объекта в сессии, вставляем вызов `ajax`-а, который отправляет `getTimezoneOffset` на сервер - в специальный контроллер, который создает объект и кладет его в сессию.

---

Клиент - браузер.

Сервер - компьютер с ASP.NET веб-приложением.

Дату/время в базе данных следует хранить как UTC.

Comment: Эта сторона мне понятна, вы имеете в виду между пользователем и сайтом. А я хочу между сайтом и сервером передачу реализовать

Comment: @vusaldev Что в данном случае является "сервером"?

Comment: схема такая: пользователь -> сайт ASP.NET MVC 4 -> сервер .exe служба на .NET -> SQL Server.

Comment: @vusaldev "я хочу делать конвертацию смещения именно на сервере" - это значит - "в коде C#"?

Comment: да, на этапе получения данных из базы и записи в базу, реализовать в слое DAL всю конвертацию. Тип хранения выбрал datetimeoffset.

Comment: В чем преимущество хранить смещение на сервере? Вы на сервере рендерите html?

Comment: @tym32167 я? да.

Comment: понял, спасибо.